# basic inheritance with coffeescript, child override not called

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, marionette

I am getting an unexpected behavior. Where I overrode a function in my child class but the one from the parent class is still being called. What am I doing wrong?

```
class MyClassA
    myFnc: ->
        debugger
        @myFncTest()

    myFncTest: ->
        ## this one is called eventhough it's defined in extended class

class MyClassB extends MyClassA
    myFncTest: ->
        debugger


inst = new MyClassB()
inst.myFnc()
```

**Edit**

I am using Marionette modules which wraps in two separate files MyClassA and MyClassB

```
MyApp.module("MyModuleA", function(MyModule, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _)

class MyClassA
        myFnc: ->
            debugger
            @myFncTest()

        myFncTest: ->
            ## this one is called eventhough it's defined in extended class

MyApp.module("MyModuleB", function(MyModule, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _)

class MyClassB extends MyApp.MyModuleA.MyClassA

        myFncTest: ->
            debugger


    inst = new MyClassB()
    inst.myFnc()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I write the following:

```
class MyClassA
    myFnc: ->
        console.log 'myFnc'
        @myFncTest()

    myFncTest: ->
        console.log 'hello from A'
        ## this one is called eventhough it's defined in extended class

class MyClassB extends MyClassA
    myFncTest: ->
        console.log 'hello from B'


inst = new MyClassB()
inst.myFnc()
```

and run

```
➜ coffee test.coffee
myFnc
hello from B
```

I get only "Hello from B".

I guess you are either calling `super()` , or they are other side effects in  your code

I use the latest version of coffeescript:

```
➜ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.9.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only other specific environment difference I have is I am using Marionette modules see edit

Comment: Ah it works!!! It only starte working when I upgraded coffeescript to 1.9.1. I was previously on 1.8.0 and it was not working like described above. Thank you